# Create a custom shape drawable using layer-list drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How to create a drawable that looks like below image using layer-list drawable? [image]

Comment: Because it's the only drawable type that able to draw something like this. Using layer list drawable you can combine different shapes.

Comment: i can see only one shape,  the red one

Comment: There are only 4 drawable shape types in Android.. Rectangle, oval, line and ring. For these Kindda shapes you have to use layer-list

Comment: no,  you can use a NinePatchDrawable or ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape object passed to its constructor

Comment: How do i do this using ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape object? can you provide an example code.

Comment: read ShapeDrawable and Shape javadocs